# String.format using a exception.getMessage() as a format

Tags: java, string, exception, formatter

I have a question related to String.format in JAVA.
My HibernateDao Class is responsible for persisting entities and will throw an exception in case I have any constrain violation. The message contains a %s and will be used as a format in the upper layers, as I should be worried about types in this layer, thus can't identify what object I could not persist.

```
public Entity persistEntity(Entity entity) {
    if (entity == null || StringUtils.isBlank(entity.getId()))
        throw new InternalError(CANNOT_INSERT_NULL_ENTITY);

    try {
        getHibernateTemplate().save(entity);
    } catch (DataAccessException e) {
        if (e.getCause() instanceof ConstraintViolationException)
            throw new HibernateDaoException("%s could not be persisted. Constraint violation.");
        throw new HibernateDaoException(e);
    }

    return entity;
}
```

And then in my DaoHelper Class I will catch this exception and throw a new one, with a formatted message.

```
//Correct Code
public Entity create(Entity object) throws MyException {
    try {
        return this.hibernateDao.persistEntity(object);
    } catch (HibernateDaoException he) {
        String format = he.getMessage();
        throw new MyException(String.format(format,object.getClass().getSimpleName()));
    }
}
```

My question is, why I cannot directly call the he.getMessage() in my String.format method?? And must use a 'tmp' variable instead... It just won't substitute the %s from the string.

```
//What I wished to do, but I cant.
public Entity create(Entity object) throws MyException {
    try {
        return this.hibernateDao.persistEntity(object);
    } catch (HibernateDaoException he) {
        throw new MyException(String.format(he.getMessage(),object.getClass().getSimpleName()));
    }
}
```

Thx in advance.

Comment: What result are you getting?  A simple test using he.getMessage() directly as the format works as expected for me.

Comment: @highlycaffeinated I construct an HTTP response afterwards using the message of the last exception. My tests were showing the raw String that I posted in the first exception: "%s could not be persisted. Constraint violation."

Comment: @highlycaffeinated is correct. This should work as you expect it to. You might want to check that when your test fails, maybe you are throwing the wrapper HiberateDaoException(e) and not the exception because of the constraintviolation.

Comment: I will retry my test and post the results again shortly!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be closed, as the intended behavior is working. As @Kal and @highlycaffeinated commented, calling the `getMessage()` directly does work, something must have happened with my build and did not update correctly. However the messages do appear correctly now.
Thanks for the quick answers :)

Comment: Instead of closing this, just mark your answer here as "Accepted" - if someone else comes across the same issue, maybe finding this will save them some effort.