# Throwable constructor with message format parameters

Tags: java, exception

Is there any reason to `Throwable` class not having a constructor with parameters to format message string?

I believe a constructor like that would allow a much more clean and elegant exception handling.

```
throw new Exception(String.format("Illegal value. Must be between %s and %s", min, max));
```

IMHO would look much better like this:

```
throw new Exception("Illegal value. Must be between {} and {}", min, max);
```

in a medium/big application, this could save a lot of typing and increase readability.

I wonder why Sun/Oracle haven't done yet this change. How can I open a "ticket" to Oracle to analyze my suggestion?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7016578/string-format-using-a-exception-getmessage-as-a-format

Comment: "I wonder why Sun/Oracle haven't done yet this change." - I guess only Sun/Oracle might know ...

Comment: May be because there are other wrapper classes as well. There should be some consistency, specially when String.format(..) method is already existing to achieve this.

Comment: probably because formatting the exception is a separate concern from throwing the exception, and needs to be implemented in a different place. you don't want the code that throws the exception to have to care about localization. see how Spring uses MessageSource.

Answer (score 3):

I agree that there could have been some nicer constructors for exception types.

However it is easy to write helper methods for this yourself.

```
public static String outOfBoundsMessage(int min, int max, int actualValuePassed) {
    return String.format("Illegal value. %s is not between %s and %s", actualValuePassed, min, max);
}
```

Then you can do

```
throw new Exception(outOfBoundsMessage(0, 10, 15));
```

Comment: This is the current approach here where I work, but could be better, as we have hundreds of exceptions and (almost) all of them are formatted with parameters.

Comment: @andrucz There is no silver bullet unfortunately. Arguably `Throwable` could have been given a constructor `Throwable(String format, Object... args)` that invokes `this(String.format(format, args));`.